# Ubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 9380 : Small freezes and jumping touchpad

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, touchpad, dell, xps

I have just received my new Dell XPS 9380, pre-installed with ubuntu 18.04. It's awesome and everything seems to be running smoothly except for two things :

- Sometimes typing in a terminal will freeze the system for 3-4 seconds. (I can see the clock stopped in the top bar). Then the letters typed during this interval will appear all at once. It seems that it happens mainly after maintaining backspace to delete something, but it's hard to reproduce consistently. However it's very annoying;
- Sometimes while using the TouchPad it stops working for a few seconds, or jump somewhere in the screen.

I've done quite a bit of research of the subject, but it's hard to find something specific to XPS 9380 and ubuntu 18.04, and I don't want to break anything. (I've seen some people talking about conflicting device for the touchpad, and problems with the perfomance mode of intel graphic card for the freezes). My system is completly up to date.

Not sure if it's relevant but here's the output of `xinput --list`

```
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL08AF:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and the ouput of `lshw`

```
description: Notebook
    product: XPS 13 9380 (08AF)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: 9X66YT2
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.2 dmi-3.2 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=XPS sku=08AF uuid=44454C4C-5800-1036-8036-B9C04F595432
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0KTW76
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /9X66YT2/CNCMK0094302C0/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.2.1
          date: 02/14/2019
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 35
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: K4EBE304EC-EGCG
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             slot: System Board Memory
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0,5 ns)
             product: K4EBE304EC-EGCG
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             slot: System Board Memory
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 3e
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 256KiB
          capacity: 256KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 3f
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:2
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 40
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 41
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1997MHz
          capacity: 4600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 0b
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:155 memory:db000000-dbffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 0b
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:dc510000-dc517fff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dc524000-dc524fff
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:dc523000-dc523fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:dc500000-dc50ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-1035-oem xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
                   vendor: CN09357GLOG008CLA282A01
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 80.08
                   capabilities: usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Foxconn / Hon Hai
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-1035-oem xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dc51c000-dc51dfff memory:dc522000-dc522fff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:4f800000-4f800fff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.1
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:4f801000-4f801fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:157 memory:dc51f000-dc51ffff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122 memory:dc400000-dc4fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:138 memory:dc400000-dc400fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 32
                serial: 9c:b6:d0:97:b4:23
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-1035-oem firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:156 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:124 ioport:4000(size=8192) memory:ac000000-da0fffff ioport:60000000(size=1241513984)
           *-pci
                description: PCI bridge
                product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: 02
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=pcieport
                resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=8192) memory:ac000000-da0fffff ioport:60000000(size=1241513984)
              *-pci:0
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:1f10-1f0f irq:16 memory:da000000-da0fffff
                 *-generic
                      description: System peripheral
                      product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 NHI (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                      version: 02
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
                      configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
                      resources: irq:16 memory:da000000-da03ffff memory:da040000-da040fff
              *-pci:1
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:01.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:41410-4140f irq:126 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:ac000000-c3efffff ioport:60000000(size=536870912)
              *-pci:2
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:02.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:1f10-1f0f irq:18 memory:c3f00000-c3ffffff
                 *-usb
                      description: USB controller
                      product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                      vendor: Intel Corporation
                      physical id: 0
                      bus info: pci@0000:39:00.0
                      version: 02
                      width: 32 bits
                      clock: 33MHz
                      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress xhci cap_list
                      configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                      resources: irq:130 memory:c3f00000-c3f0ffff
                    *-usbhost:0
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 4.15.0-1035-oem xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 0
                         bus info: usb@3
                         logical name: usb3
                         version: 4.15
                         capabilities: usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                    *-usbhost:1
                         product: xHCI Host Controller
                         vendor: Linux 4.15.0-1035-oem xhci-hcd
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@4
                         logical name: usb4
                         version: 4.15
                         capabilities: usb-3.10
                         configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=10000Mbit/s
              *-pci:3
                   description: PCI bridge
                   product: JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016]
                   vendor: Intel Corporation
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: pci@0000:04:04.0
                   version: 02
                   width: 64 bits
                   clock: 33MHz
                   capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
                   configuration: driver=pcieport
                   resources: iomemory:51510-5150f irq:127 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:c4000000-d9ffffff ioport:80000000(size=704643072)
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.4
             version: f0
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:125 memory:dc300000-dc3fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:6e:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:dc300000-dc303fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:158 memory:dc518000-dc51bfff memory:dc200000-dc2fffff
        *-serial:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 30
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:dc51e000-dc51e0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 30
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:fe010000-fe010fff
  *-battery
       product: DELL H754V8C
       vendor: LG
       physical id: 1
       version: 12/14/2018
       serial: 0683
       slot: Sys. Battery Bay
       capacity: 51990mWh
       configuration: voltage=7,6V
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question, hope someone can help me out !

EDIT 1: I forgot to mention that the freezes when typing doesn't happen when using the Ubuntu text based terminals. It happens only in the gui terminal (I'm using GNOME the default desktop that shipped with 18.04)