# DELL XPS 9380 Touchpad skip ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, dell, xps

I'm using the new XPS 13 (9380) that comes pre installed with ubuntu 18.04.2.

I was experiencing [some issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133191/ubuntu-18-04-on-dell-xps-9380-small-freezes-and-jumping-touchpad) With the keyboard and the touchpad.

Installing the LTS hardware enablement stack seems to have solved the keyboard freezing issues. However the touchpad still jump from time to time. Seems to happen more often when the laptop is running on battery.

I've noticed that when running `xinput list` in a terminal, there is two 'touchpad' device. Could that be the origin of the issues ?

```
xinput list | grep -i touchpad
⎜   ↳ DELL08AF:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Thank you for your time, hope someone can help me out with this !

Addendum 1 : list props for 'Dell08AF' touchpad

```
Device 'DELL08AF:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (144):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (282): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (283): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (284):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (285):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (288):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (289):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (292):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (293):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (294):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (295):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (296):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (297): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (298):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (299):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (300):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (301):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (302): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (303): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (304): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (305): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event9"
    Device Product ID (271):    1739, 30383
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (306):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (307):   1
```

Addendum 2 : list-props for 'synaptics' touchpad :

```
xinput --list-props 15
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (144):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (146): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Tapping Enabled (282): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (283): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (284):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (285):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (286):   0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (287):   0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (288):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (289):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (290):   1
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (291):   0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (292):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (293):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (294):    1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (295):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (296):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (297): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (298):    0, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (299):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (300):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (301):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (302): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (303): 0.000000
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (304): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (305): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (267): 1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (268):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (269):    0, 0
    Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (271):    2, 7
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (306):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (307):   1
```

EDIT : I have switched to the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which seems to improve the situation a lot. I still sometimes get some weird behavior from the touchpad but way less often.

Comment: Unrelated but do you have a 4k display? My 4k display has loads of flickering issues: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136409/new-xps-13-9380-with-ubuntu-flicker-problems

Comment: I'd say having two drivers doesn't help, but having one doesn't solve either.
I have one, but also impacted by the issue:
```
xinput list | grep -i touch
⎜   ↳ DLL075B:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Comment: @AndreMiras Well I guess that's not the origin of the issue then =/ Have you tried the [Hardware Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)? It seemed to have improved my situation a lot.

Comment: @PauloMatos Nope, Full HD display

Comment: Yes thanks, I was actually giving it a try following this guide https://www.dell.com/support/article/es/es/esdhs1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en on 18.04. So far so good, but I also had a shit load of firmware updates the next reboot so could also be related. Let's see after a week or so :)