# New XPS 13 9380 with ubuntu 18.04 flicker problems

Tags: display, dell, xps, flicker, 4k-monitor

I just received my new xps 13 9380 with a 4k display and with ubuntu pre-installed and since I started it that I am getting flickring problems.

Videos here:

https://photos.app.goo.gl/1PkL2HrjMBP41aML9

https://photos.app.goo.gl/CMzmMwrCPH5wh8aw6

Could this be a ubuntu configuration problem or should I report a faulty display to Dell?

After checking the BIOS (version 1.2.1 - latest) it might be an ubuntu config issue since there's no flickering so hardware is fine.

Comment: Have you tried this boot parameter setting?   `i915.fastboot=1` kernel parameter. Fastboot helps provide a clean, flicker-free Linux boot experience.
New 5.1 kernel will include it by default on Skylake and newer

Comment: @oldfred Thanks for the suggestion, I was not aware of fastboot but unfortunately it didn't help. When the screen flickers, it is almost like you can see a deformed version of the screen underneath, almost as if there's a double buffering issue. No idea what it could be.

Comment: I have ended up reporting a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1826125

Comment: Do not know if he mentions anything useful in article? Dell XPS 13 9380 + Intel Core i7 8565U Ubuntu Linux Performance Benchmarks
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps-9380&num=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug in intel drivers causes flickering. 
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1826125
Specifically:
https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=110511#c15

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the standard Ubuntu 18.04 LTS download but it was fixed once I installed the OEM image from the dell website.

[Ubuntu 18.04 XPS 9380 .iso](https://downloads.dell.com/FOLDER05544477M/1/Dell_XPS_9380_20190321_210_A02.iso)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. In the meantime we have found a bug in the intel drivers causing this. Refer to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1826125

Comment: Tried that, same problem as the 18.04 ISO (an 19 for the matter) unfortunately. I guess I'll have to wait for the bug to be resolved before being able to dual boot on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Dynamic Backlight Control in Bios.