# Dual boot win 10/Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I'l try to make this short and sweet. New Dell XPS, did what I always do is re-partition for Ubuntu. It screws-up Win 10 so a re-install. Created two partitions for `/` and `/home`. 250Gb root and 20Gb `/home`.

I had a hell of a time getting this thing to boot. Initially it was Windows only and after the highly touted command prompt registry fix it worked but, no grub and no windows. I had a hell of time getting windows back but still cannot find a fix for grub. I think most all the issues are related to secure boot but, I can't put my finger on the issue. I have reinstalled both OS's more than I would like to admit.

Only two partitions for Ubuntu: `/` & `/home`. 16GB RAM so I thought there is little need for a swap drive. Both Ubuntu partitions are defined as logical.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Keep in mind I know Linux and can navigate and install but, not an expert by any stretch.

Comment: If you only have one hard drive -- I would format the entire drive as GPT and then start by dividing into two partitions of empty space with no file system, one for Windows and the other for all your Ubuntu.  Install Windows first to the first partition on the drive.  Then run the Ubuntu installer and it should give you the option to install alongside windows & set up the rest of the drive.  Sometimes if you get crazy with partitions, esp before the Windows install, you will encounter problems.

Comment: This ^^^ and 260gB for root and 20GB for /home? It makes sense to have the most for your usespace, root doesn't need much, so the other way around is what makes sense.

Comment: ^^^This! FYI, I have a pretty complete installation and my root is 13 Gb and my home is 132 Gb. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: See  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Be sure both installs are UEFI. With Dell you must change drive to AHCI, but install AHCI drivers first into Windows. Most Dell need UEFI update & if SSD firmware update. Dell 9380 Dell has 18.04 image with correct drivers
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136409/new-xps-13-9380-with-ubuntu-18-04-flicker-problems & 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en