# How to dual boot Ubuntu on "Dell XPS 13 9380"?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, dell, xps

I am currently running Windows 10 and want to boot from a MicroSD Ubuntu.iso bootable device made in Rufus3-9.
My question is, how do add the usb device into the UEFI boot order.
So far all I have is the following:
[When I press F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WypWF.jpg)

I have disabled Secure Boot in the Bios setting and even tried AHCI mode in the Sata configuration.

None of these worked. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does system boot from your SD cards? Not all systems do. Can you use an USB adapter so seen as an USB drive? You may have to turn on allow USB boot. And Rufus can make just BIOS or UEFI installers. UEFI-CSM is really BIOS boot. CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136409/new-xps-13-9380-with-ubuntu-18-04-flicker-problems & 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

I had 18.04 installed via SD Card on my 9380. Since then I rebuilt my machine dual booting win10/Ubuntu 20.04. Works like a charm.

I didn't need to disable Secure Boot as it's supported on 18.04 upwards (maybe before). I think the option you're missing was to enable SD card boot. What I had to do:

- Disable Bitlocker
- Enable USB Boot Support
- Enable Thunderbolt Boot Support
- Put
  Fastboot to Thorough
- Enable SD Card boot ( System Configuration |
  Miscellaneous Devices | Secure Digital (SD) Card Boot )

Get Windows to use AHCI
 - Go into MSConfig and set a minimal safe boot
 - Restart
 - Enter BIOS
 - Change to AHCI
 - Boot into Windows and turn off safe mode again (Win should now use the AHCI Drivers rather than that odd RAID)

Haven't played with it alot yet but the only issues I noticed after installation were

- Wifi not enabled by default. Connecting to the web on Ehternet and apt-get update/upgrade seemed to rectify this.
- SD Slot not recognised - I haven't attempted to rectify this yet

It was slow to install 18.04 from SD IIRC. I used a USB key the for 20.04 and the installation flew.