# Ubuntu installation on Dell XPS 9380 issues

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dell, xps

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows. There are following issues:

- I flashed the Ubuntu installation package into my flash drive thru Dell recovery tool. But  when I’m restarting the machine and pressing F12, it is not showing me USB drive as one of my options. So I added that manually by going in to the boot sequence and chose grubx64.efi for Ubuntu and it worked also. But I’m not sure why it didn’t show USB drive as my option on that black screen
- Now using flash drive I went in to the Ubuntu for installation. But there in the list of spaces it is not showing me the free space of 100GB on SSD which I created before starting the whole process. It is only showing me the flash drive unallocated space which is only 27 GB. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Dell 9380 Dell has 18.04 image with correct drivers
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1136409/new-xps-13-9380-with-ubuntu-18-04-flicker-problems & 
https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en
Dell XPS 13 9380 + Intel Core i7 8565U Ubuntu Linux Performance Benchmarks
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=dell-xps-9380&num=1
Dell typically needs UEFI update, SSD firmware update, change Intel RST to AHCI & add AHCI drivers into Windows.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

http://tutorials.ubuntu.com have the preferred methods for downloading then  verifying the ISO file, the making a Live USB or Live DVD, before installation. Using other tools such as that Dell app are not recommended.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try this way.

Comment: Hi I tried again by using Rufus. I’m not sure again it is not detecting my SSD for installation.

Comment: If the Ubiquity Installer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity does not see the SSD, either that SSD is formatted using Windows as a Dynamic Disk (which Linux can't access),  or there;s a problem with the SSD or its cabling. Please run `_lsblk | grep -v "loop"  && df -h | grep -v "loop"` and highlight the text which appears in the terminal window as a result. Copy the text, return here, click [edit], and paste that text into your question. Please don't use Add Comment as Comments have no formatting and we have a very tough time reading the result.